# UIWebview Not detecting links

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with text which contains web links inside it. The test is being displayed from DB.

For some links inside text, UIWebView detects links and for some links it does not. In DB all the links are written with same format that after space, I have link. Please help me that why some links are working and not?

Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *newString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><script> document.ontouchmove = function(event) { if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault(); } </script><script type='text/javascript'>function myFunction() { window.open('http://www.otherlink.com');} function myFunction1(){window.open('http://www.newlink.com');}</script><style type='text/css'>.layout {padding:6px 10px 12px; width:300px; height:398px} *{padding:0; margin:0;line-height:normal}img{margin-bottom:10px;width:300px} button{padding-bottom:7px; border:none; text-decoration:underline;text-align:right;float:right; font-family:ArnhemPro-Blond; font-size:13px; color:#666666}.headline {color:#000000; font-family:PublicoHeadline-Light; font-size:28px; padding-bottom:4px;}.subHeadLine {color:#585c74; font-family:ApexNew-Book;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:14px;}.fullText {font-size:13px;font-family:ArnhemPro-Blond;margin-bottom:7px;} .fullText p { color:black; font-size:13px; margin-bottom:7px} .fullText a { text-decoration: underline; color: #A6091E; font-weight:bold;} .clr {clear:both;} </style> <body><div class='layout'><p class='headline'>%@</p><p class='subHeadLine'>%@</p><img src='%@'/><p class='fullText'>%@</p><button onclick='myFunction()'>Try it</button><div class ='clr'></div><button onclick='myFunction1()'>Try it Next</button></div></body></html>",headLine,subHeadLine,path,fullText] ;
```

It shows text+image+2 buttons.

Comment: could you show us the contents of UIWebview ?

Comment: It is HTML string and if you mean to show text than I will paste it or you mean HTML string.

Comment: we want to see the html string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an encoding issue. just changed encoding to

> NSUTF8StringEncodeing and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Where did you add this line of code with the NSUTF8 String Encoding? I saw the string, you want to load in your webview, am i right? Do you load the content with [webview loadHTMLString:<the text from above> baseURL:nil];? I'm facing the same problem and i try to find simularities. Best regards

Comment: Yes I loaded content with loadHTMLString method. There was an encoding issue as webview was using default encoding and when tried NSUTF8, it worked. I would like to see your code (HTML string) that how u doing this.